# Model an object that can have different fields base on a type property

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-schema

I have an object which can have different fields based on the type property of the object

```
class Expense {
   String id;
   String type; // "MILEAGE" or "PERDIEM"
   String commonAttribute1;
   // there are too many common attribute
   Mileage mileage;
   PerDiem perDiem;
}
```

Mileage and PerDiem have different attributes and based on the type, one of them will be null and the other one will be populated.

What is the best way to model such relationship?

I have thought of two ways:

1- Creating different tables for mileage and per diems and link them to the expenses table through a foreign key with one to one relationship.

2- Add both on the same table and based on the type I can fetch from the table any attributes I want, but many columns will be non used.

Comment: Perhaps another option could be an indicator column with columns shared according to the indicator so max wasted/null columns would be the difference between the number of attributes of each type. SQLite's ability to store any type of value in any column could come into play.

Comment: Nice one! There are like 4 types and it'll be really messy to look something up when making a query for example.